# ThrottleRequests::addHeaders(): Argument #1 ($response) must be of type in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-middleware, laravel-sanctum, laravel-api

I am trying to give a message to user in Laravel Sanctum through a middlewate. Is users' contact validated? If validated they will receive the data, if not validated they will receive a message please validate your number.

I sent the bearer token that I generated. And I can get the data of user in middleware. But not getting the message that I want.

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = auth()->user();
        if ($user->mobile_verified != 1) {
            // return APIHelper::ApiResponse(true, 400, 'Mobile No is not verified please verify.', null);
            return 'Condition';
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

Errors of above code is in title. And I also pasting those errors below.

Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::addHeaders(): Argument #1 ($response) must be of type Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response, string given.

Answer (score 0):

Middleware can only return responses, or forward the request to the next middleware handler by calling `$next($request)`. In your `if ($user->mobile_verified != 1)` condition, you're returning the string `"Condition"` rather than a response object. Do this instead:

```php
if ($user->mobile_verified != 1)
    return response('Condition', $status);
```